# Session Timeout doesn't work by using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have below script. When the time is 60 sec or less the popup is appear(which asks user for whether to log out or continue) and when I click on continue from that button of popup it reloads the page. The issue is sometimes it goes logged out. Not sure whats wrong with below code. Any help is appriciated.

```
var startTime = new Date();
var endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + (@FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMilliseconds));
var i = 0;

function updateTimeoutDuration() {
        var diff = Math.floor((new Date() - endTime) / 1000) * -1;
        if (diff > 0) {
            minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60);
            seconds = Math.floor(diff % 60);
            $('#timeout-countdown #remaining-time').html(((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' + ((seconds < 10) ? '0' : '') + seconds);
            console.log("Timeout - countdown",((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' + ((seconds < 10) ? '0' : '') + seconds);
            $('#dialog-timeout-confirm #timeout-countdown-popup #remaining-time-popup').html(((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' + ((seconds < 10) ? '0' : '') + seconds);

            // popup message will display when 60 sedconds remaining
            if (diff < 60) {

                // Autometically logged out when 0 second when timer will reach to 0 second
                if (diff < 1) {
                    $("#logoutfrm").submit();
                }

                $('#timeout-countdown #remaining-time').addClass('warning');
                $('#dialog-timeout-confirm #timeout-countdown-popup #remaining-time-popup').addClass('warning');
                //Popup message will open
                if (i == 0) {
                    i = 1;
                    popupMessage();
                }

                i = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = '@FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl' + '?redirectUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname);
        }
    }
    $(function () {
        setInterval(updateTimeoutDuration, 1000);
    });

 function popupMessage()
    {
        $("#dialog-timeout-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 240,
            modal: true,
            buttons: [
                        {
                            text: "Log out",
                            "class": 'popup_logoutbtn',
                            click: function() {
                                var logoutfrm = document.getElementById('logoutForm');
                                if(logoutfrm != undefined && logoutfrm != null && logoutfrm != ''){
                                    //logoutfrm.submit();
                                    $("#logoutfrm").submit();
                                }
                                else{
                                    window.location.href = '@FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl' + '?redirectUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Stay Logged In",
                            "class": 'popup_staylogoutbtn',
                            click: function() {
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Comment: Not sure, but if this is an issue, I assume the page may be opened in background by the user. If he doesn't see the popup in the 60 seconds reminaing, it will be too late when he clicks...

Comment: no only one page is open. no other page is opened in other browser. And also it happens around 11 secs